# Approximation to the number of seconds in a year?

Tags: time, unit-conversion

Is there any mathematical formula which shows that there are approximately $\pi \times 10^7$ seconds in one year. I understand that the pi is probably due to the earth's circular orbit, but am not sure where the rest could come from .

Comment: $\pi$ has nothing to do with it. Where did you find that? To find the number of seconds in a year, multiply 1 year by 365.25 days by 24 hours by 60 minutes by 60 seconds.

Comment: I know, but pi*10^7 is sometimes given as a rough approximation to be used if you dont have a calculator

Comment: For example: http://www.physics.corpus.cam.ac.uk/wp-content/uploads/2012/02/every_physicist.pdf

Comment: It works fine, but it seems to be a coincidence, unlike, say, the distance the Earth travels in one year.

Comment: **Why does a nano century equate to $\pi$ seconds? ** Either cesium atoms know about earth's trajectory around sun, can compute $\pi$, and play a trick on us. Or... This is an (approximate) coincidence. Fait vos jeux...

Comment: When you consider that a second is an arbitrary unit of time (that wasn't chosen to make $\pi*10^7$ seconds in a year), you should realize that it must be a complete coincidence.

Comment: @Johannes Cesium atoms hardly play any role on the duration of the second. The definition based on cesium atom was formed long after the length of a second was decided. (Compare to $g=\pi^2\text{ m}/\text{s}^2$)

Comment: It's a complete coincidence, and the approximation is nowhere close enough to make sense.

Comment: @WouterLievens sure it makes sense as a mnemonic used for estimation. Some people like to do math in their head. No tables, no calculators, no Google. Estimating is a physicist's power tool.

Comment: Do many professional physicists tend to do a lot of estimating (using just their heads) out of curiosity?

Comment: Just idle (useless?) thoughts:

 * It is no coincidence that there are about 365 days in a year, and 360 degrees in a circle...

 * Earth's orbit is not circular, just nearly so.

 * The number of seconds in a year is not a constant anyway, but varies observationally each year by a few fractions.

Answer (score 12):

It's a unit conversion:
$$
1\,{\rm yr}=\frac{365\,{\rm days}}{\rm year}\times\frac{24\,{\rm hrs}}{1\,{\rm day}}\times\frac{3600\,{\rm sec}}{1\,{\rm hour}}=3.1556926\times10^7\,{\rm sec}
$$
Since $3.1557$ is (somewhat) close to $\pi\sim3.1416$, we use the approximation you cite.

Technically, the year is actually 365.25 days long, so using that gives a slightly better approximation that gets one to $3.15576\times10^7\,{\rm sec}$, though most sources I've seen simply use 365 days. Both values are still less than half a percent off of the $\pi\cdot10^7$ value.

Comment: [obligatory xkcd link](http://xkcd.com/1047/)

Comment: @Floris: In this case, the xkcd link should really be the answer, not just an obligatory joke comment.

Comment: @R.. Except that the original cartoon didn't have this expression, and Randall subsequently got it wrong by a factor 10 in the subtitle... But yes it's a great one!

Comment: +1, but it would be better if you changed that 365 to 365.25. That value is something every physicist should know. For one thing, 365.25 days is 1/100 of an astronomical century, which is something every astronomer knows by heart. For another, a year of 365.25 years was good enough for humanity for over a thousand years. (And it's obviously still good enough for astronomers!)

Comment: @DavidHammen: Most every source I have seen use 365 days & get the same value I have, even [Google does it](https://www.google.com/search?client=opera&q=1+year+in+seconds). I will add the extra pair of decimal places to the answer though

Comment: @kyle - while you are at it use 365 days 5 hours 48 minutes 46 seconds - that is actually what Google tells you when you type "length of year", and it takes account of the "leap every four but not every hundred but every 400" thing... It is 31,556,926 seconds

Answer (score 2):

The observation that "π seconds is a nanocentury" is attributed to [Tom Duff](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tom_Duff), who is known to computer programmers as the inventor of "Duff's Device".  There's nothing magical about the fact that 1/10,000,000 of a planetary orbit should equal roughly π/86400 of a planetary day (not the same thing as a planetary rotation, btw, since the orientation of the side of the earth facing the sun changes during the orbit); if the earth turned at a slightly different speeds, then one might say "e seconds is a nanocentury", but it would be no more meaningful.